# core data, NSManagedObject changed between app versions

Tags: iphone, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an app at the App-Store right now that uses Core-Data with persistent store to save the data as SQL-Lite-store-type, locally on the device.

Actually the Model is very simple, I have only one NSManagedObject in it, called "Product".

**In the next version I want to edit "Product" properties** in the following way: add a new property and remove 5 properties. (Without the app crashing because of the inconsistency...)

Plus, **on the first launch of the application after the user upgrade I want to delete the old stored-DB**, because it won't be relevant to the application any more.

I read "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide", but still not sure what is the best practice in this case. (Should I use "Lightweight Migration"?)

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Lightweight Migration is the simplest choice here. If all you are doing is adding properties, lightweight migration lets you avoid dealing with the inconsistency errors.

Comment: I need to remove 5 properties!!!
As far as I understood it is not supported by "lightweight migration".

And what about: how to delete the old stored-DB on upgrade version first launch?

Comment: adding and removing properties is fine. The documentation doesn't explicitly say it supports adding properties in lightweight migration but it does. You also don't need to delete the old database when preforming a lightweight migration.

If you want to delete the old database you could do so in the app delegate where the persistent store is added to the persistent store coordinator using the following code:

'[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];'